# pcase not recognising string matches

Tags: string, conditional-statements, emacs

Am attempting to insert either a Latex Command or a UTF-8 Symbol
to a buffer, but the `pcase` is giving me `"No Match"` when selecting
`"bigodot"`.

`grafm` in expected to me modified by removing the `UTF-8` Symbol, by
taking the first word before the first space, and use just the string
descriptor `"bigodot"` for use with the `pcase` clause.

```
(defun imprint (selector kmstr &optional grapheme)
  "Insert Latex Command or the equivalent UTF-8 grapheme."

  (if (or (not grapheme) (equal selector "Command"))
      (insert kmstr)
    (insert grapheme)))

;;-------------------------------------

(defun bigops (grafm seltr)
  "Binary Operations."

  (interactive
    (let ( (csel '("Symbol" "Command"))
           (cseq '("bigodot ⨀" "bigoplus ⨁︁" "bigotimes ⨂︁")) )

      (list
        (completing-read "Grapheme: " cseq nil t "bigcap ⋂")
        (completing-read "Selector: " csel nil t "Command")) ))

  (setq grafm (car (split-string grafm)))
  (message "Grafm: .%S." grafm)

  (pcase grafm
    ("bigodot" (imprint seltr "\\bigodot" "⨀"))
    ("bigoplus︁" (imprint seltr "\\bigoplus" "⨁︁"))
    ("bigotimes︁" (imprint seltr "\\bigotimes" "⨂︁"))
    (_  (message "%s" "No Match")) ))
```

Comment: I can include it, it should not be the problem because I get `"No Match"`.  It looks as if 'grafm' in not being recognised properly.

Comment: When I print `grafm`, it seems good, giving `bigoplus`.  Something weird is going on.

Comment: We are getting on to something.  Something is happening with `pcase`.

Comment: Whatever happens with `imprint` should not affect `pcase` at all.

Comment: Have included the workings of `imprint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hidden characters, codepoint 65025, at various places in the strings you've entered as `pcase` matches that are causing the unexpected match failures.

You can visualize them with

```
(defun my-display-hidden (&optional remove)
  "Show/hide the hidden '︁' (0xfe01) characters."
  (interactive "P")
  (if remove (remove-overlays)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward "︁" nil t) ; (0xfe01)
        (let ((ov (make-overlay (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))))
          (overlay-put ov 'display
                       (buttonize "(0xfe01)"
                                  (let ((pos (match-beginning 0)))
                                    (lambda (_) (describe-char pos)))))
          (overlay-put ov 'face 'font-lock-warning-face))))))
```

Comment: Have no idea how they are getting introduced.  I write them as normal text in emacs.

Comment: Have now identified those characters.  Thank you so very much for finding these things out.  Would never have guessed it.